# Mockito - clear argument captor pr

Tags: java, mockito

My problem is best described by a simple example. Here is my class:

```
public class App  
{
    void doFirst(String s){
        if(s.equals("hello")){
            return;
        }
        doSecond(s);
    }

    void doSecond(String s){

    }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
public void testApp() {
        App a = spy(new App());
        ArgumentCaptor<String> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        doNothing().when(a).doSecond(argument.capture());   
        a.doFirst("bye");
        assertEquals("bye", argument.getValue());
        a.doFirst("hello");
        assertEquals(null, argument.getValue());        
    }
```

The problem is that that second assert fails becauseargument.getValue() has the value from previos call to doFirst. Can i somehow clear argument after first assertion so it will be null by the time it reaches second one?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you just create another `ArgumentCaptor`?

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you are testing two different conditions -

- that `doSecond` gets called with the right argument when `s` is not `"hello"`
- that `doSecond` does not get called, when `s` is `"hello"`

That should be two separate tests.

Also, don't use an `ArgumentCaptor` and `assertEquals`.  This is what `verify` is for.  You could write your test class like this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AppTest {
    @Spy App toTest;

    @Test
    public void doSecondIsCalledWhenArgumentIsNotHello() {
        toTest.doFirst("bye");
        verify(toTest).doSecond("bye");
    }

    @Test
    public void doSecondIsNotCalledWhenArgumentIsHello() {
        toTest.doFirst("hello");
        verify(toTest, never()).doSecond(anyString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesent quite work for me. In this example this cant be seen but in my actual code the second result is based on the first one so they have to be in the same test. Imagine that there is an counter in first function and with every call it increments and when its > 2 then the function returns, otherwise it calls doSeconds().

Comment: OK, you can combine these in one test; but maybe you want to change the second `verify` to `verify(toTest, never()).doSecond("hello");` - Just make sure that the name of the test method accurately reflects the condition that you're testing.  Don't just call it `testApp` or `testDoSecond` or something of that nature.